# Docker build doesn't detect changes in React production build files

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile, docker-build

I am trying to run a React application in an NGINX Alpine container, but whenever I make a change in the React app, create a production build again and copy updated build folder from my machine in the container, the old version of the application is still running

My Dockerfile looks like this

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY ./nginx_conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY ./build/ /var/www/build/
EXPOSE 80
```

I tried building the image without using cache(`sudo docker build --no-cache -t image_name .`), deleting the image and then building it again, and even changed the name of the build folder from my machine and tried to copy it in different folders in the container(of course modifying the server configuration accordingly)

The server configuration looks like this

```
user                            nginx;
worker_processes                auto;

error_log                       /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;


events {
    worker_connections          1024;
}

http {
    include                     /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type                application/octet-stream;
    sendfile                    on;
    access_log                  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    keepalive_timeout           3000;
    server {
        listen                  80;
        root                    /var/www/build;
        index                   index.html;
        server_name             localhost;
        client_max_body_size    64m;
        error_page              500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location / {
              try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

The dockerignore file(all files and folders except build/ are excluded)

```
/node_modules
/public
/src
/.env
/package.json
/package-lock.json
/.gitignore
/README.md
```

How to solve this problem? Have I made something wrong or is this a bug in Docker?

I know that I can just mount the build/ folder from my machine in the container but I would like to copy it in the container instead of referencing it from the container

Comment: Did you run `docker run image-name ls /var/www/build` to verify they are not in the container? and maybe can you also share the content of your dockerignore-file?

Comment: After the build, all the files are present in the container but I don't know why an older version of the app is still running

Comment: It's pretty hard to check for every file if the changes are present or not because it's a production build, maybe I should write some sort of script that does that checking for each file

Comment: can you run a `docker ps` to verify only one container is running? besides that, if only one is running > did you verify that the content in it is the newer version? if that is not the case, do you build directory really contain the new version of your code? (if you open build/index.html in your web-browser). Which command are you using to run your image?

These questions might sound stupid, but for me, it looks like it is something easy we are overlooking here. And because it is an easy thing we don't think about it.

Comment: Yes, i checked if the build folder contains the newer version and it does, I copied the build folder in my /var/www/nginx machine's folder (I have an NGINX server installed on the machine too) and it works without any problem, the problem only appears when run I the application in the container

Comment: The command used for running a container from the image is  docker run --rm  -d  -p 4000:80 image-name